# Limits of figures traced inside squares

Tags: geometry, limits

Given a square ABCD with side length 1, a line is shone from point A at a 30 degree angle from AB. As the light bounces around, the path it traces should converge to some attractor rhombi. Find the area of the limiting area not defined on any one side by the original square. (That is, “inside” the path being traced.)

(By the way, I’m only a sophomore in high school, and so I’m unversed in the ways of correct problem writing. Let me know if my problem is in any way vague or incorrect. All feedback is appreciated, but don’t be too harsh- I’ve never done something like this before.)

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I had no idea how to solve this. I barely even know enough geometry to figure out the answer even _if_ I had any idea what the limiting case looked like. Finding limits in geometry is way out of my purview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we draw a diagram of the setup we quickly see that such a rhombus would inscribe the square such that it creates four similar triangles around itself. These four similar triangles each have interior angles of $30^\circ$, $60^\circ$ and $90^\circ$. If we call the length of the side adjacent to the $30^\circ$ angle $x$ then the length of the side opposite this angle must be $1-x$ as it joins another similar triangle to form the side length of the square. This allows us to find $x$ by using some trigonometry as
$$\tan{(30^\circ)}=\frac{1-x}{x}$$
$$\implies x=\frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
Hence the area inside the limiting rhombus is given by the total area minus the area of the four similar triangles of known side lengths $x$ and $1-x$:
$$\begin{align}
\text{limiting area }
&=1-4\left(\frac12\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right)\\
&=4-2\sqrt{3}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi Peter! Thanks a lot for the clear solution. How is my question-writing? I know my math teachers do would have written this question much better, but outside of that, how did I do?

Comment: I kind of ignored the "not defined on any one side by the original square" what was that meant to mean? But other than that, the question was posed rather well in comparison to many found on this site!

Comment: I was trying to rigorously define the area that was not inside any of the similar triangles you mentioned in your solution. I didn't know exactly what the right terminology was for the area "inside" the path traced by the light- is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Oh I understand now. I would say something like "Find the value of the limiting area that lies within the traced rhombus."